# Proof of almost sure convergence of sum of iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I tried to prove the following lemma:
Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ iid nonnegative random variables with $E[X_1]=\infty$ and let $a\in(0,1)$, thus follows $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a^n exp(X_n)=\infty$ almost sure.

I tried using Borel Cantelli but failed at proving that for $L\in N$ we have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty P(\sum_{n=1}^k a^k exp(X_n)<L)<\infty$.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: There's something wrong, surely you mean $E[X_1] < \infty$.

Comment: Yes indeed, I corrected it.

Comment: Look at $P(X_n \geqslant n \log (1/a))$.

Comment: How does that help.  I'm sorry, I still don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(a^n \exp(X_n)>1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_1/\log(1/a)>n)=\infty
$$
by using the fact that $\int_0^\infty P(X_1>x)\, dx=EX_1=\infty$. Borel Cantelli implies that $a^n\exp(X_n)>1$ i.o a.s. Hence $\sum a^n\exp(X_n)=\infty$ a.s.